# MySQL or jQuery to perform these calculations?

Tags: jquery, mysql

Let me preface my question by saying that I am very new to mysql / php / jquery and this is the first application I've ever created from scratch. It's not the tightest code, but its a starting off point for me. That being said...

I've been working on a database app for a fantasy football site. Admin inputs the players and updates the stats from week to week. On the front end, the user can view and sort the results. Easy enough.

http://digitaldemo.net/kickass/projections-table.php is the link in its current state. It is n ot complete, but I wanted a working example online for you to see. I'm using Jquery's tablesorter for the sorting functionality.

What needs to happen next, and this is what has me tearing my hair out, is that the page needs to load with a default formula (e.g. 2pts for every 10 passing yrds, 6pts for every passing TD, etc... and the total would be loaded into the TFP column for each player.

Further, users would be able to change the point values and increments using the (currently non-functional) drop down boxes on the QB tab at the URL above and then click the button and have the TFP scores re-calculate.

Is it easier to use jquery or mysql to do this and how? I've looked at dozens of tutorials and all I succeed in doing is frustrating myself. I know if I can get it working for the QB tab, I can extrapolate it to the other tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you want to do calculations at the highest level you can and still get the functionality/security required: client > server > database. This sounds like something you can do in the client with javascript/jQuery, so I'd start there.

If you have more specific questions about how to do the calculations themselves, I'd open another question about that with a specific example and data.

Answer (score 0):

If you can calculate it using javascript, then use client side calculation( Javascript/jQuery), it's much faster and you can save a lot memory as well. :)

Cheers!